# Firestore rule: working on single document but not a ranged query and why is it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here are the two versions of my Firebase rule and in my mind, they should be equivalent:

Version1:

```
match /transactions/{ts} {
  function isOwner() {
    return request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/transactions/$(ts)).data.user;
  }

  allow read: if isOwner();
}
```

Version2:

```
match /transactions/{ts} {
  function isOwner() {
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
  }

  allow read: if isOwner();
}
```

Now, if I query a single document, such as `db.collection('transactions').doc(someIDHere)`, the two rules works exactly the same in terms of accepting or rejecting.

However, if I am doing a query, like `db.collection('transactions').where('user','==',userid).get()`, then only version 2 will get through, version 1 will report an error, but I don't know why this is the case. I checked the Firestore document, but there aren't sufficient explanations. Especially, what does the get() method in the rule statement mean and why is it different in range query between using get(absolute path) with using resource.data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second rule works because the filter:

```
where('user','==',userid)
```

exactly matches the constraints of the rule:

```
request.auth.uid == resource.data.user
```

(I added "auth" in there which you were missing - there is no `uid` property on `request`.)

Security rules will not perform a `get()` for each individual document that would match a collection query that could return any number of documents.  Firstly, that will not scale for large result sets, and second, there is a limit of only 10 get() per rule evaluation.  What security rules will do is check that they query constraints match query for all possible documents that could be matched.  In other words, [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  The filters on the client must match the constraints on the rules without having to evaluate them for every single document.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I am get that why the second rule will get through, but why not the first one, notice that the return `get(...).data`  is exactly equivalent to `resource.data`, so the `where('user','==',userid)` filter matches the both rules. I get it that using `resource.data` to get this value is somehow working differently by using `get(absolute_path)` under the hood, although they will return the same value, and my question is how they are different so that in the future, I can tell before I actually run the rules then encounter this kind of error.

Comment: get() requires a document fetch, but checking the client filters with the security rules just requires that they match.  So, if the client is filtering exactly as the rule says a filter is required, it doesn't actually need to know the contents of the document.  There is no "what if" situation that requires document contents.

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't realize that, and it is quite clever to directly check if a filter matches the rule and thank you for clarify that.